# Auto populated text box values from data base

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I have 4 text boxes.
I enter a value in first text box.
I want the next 3 text boxes populated values automatically from database based on value entered in the first text box.
Can this be done in asp.net?

Comment: Yes, It can be done in asp.net

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we have a text box for say a "id' of some sort, like this:

```
    <div style="text-align:right;width:300px">
        Enter Hotel ID :<asp:TextBox ID="askHotel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        <br />

        Hotel Name :<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        City  :<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        Active :<asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>

    </div>
```

And our code is:

```
Protected Sub askHotel_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles askHotel.TextChanged

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = askHotel.Text
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim rst As New DataTable
        rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        If rst.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With rst.Rows(0)
                txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName")
                txtCity.Text = .Item("City")
                Active.Checked = .Item("Active")
            End With
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]